# Defining custom latex class for org-mode export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I an trying to define a custom latex class, I will use it to export my org files to PDF. I found information about this on internet and I tried to implement the proposed solution, I wrote this in my `.emacs`:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org-latex 
(add-to-list 'org-export-latex-classes
   '("org-article"
      "\\documentclass{org-article}
      [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
      [PACKAGES]
      [EXTRA]"
      ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
      ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
      ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
      ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
      ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))))
```

So the custom class name is `org-article`, but when try to export a simple org file using this custom class :

```
#+LaTeX-CLASS: org-article
```

Emacs says `Unknown LaTex class : 'org-article'`.

It seems to me that I did everything right according to the org manual and other users in several forums. So I ask you to help me find what is wrong.

Comment: Which version of `Org` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The first item of the list, `"org-article"`, defines the name of the new class. The second item defines the document class that you are using as the basis of the your new one. So instead of writing  `\\documentclass{org-article}`, do `\\documentclass{article}` or `\\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}`, if you want to change paper and font size settings from article default.